# Palindrome check with recursive function without slicing and loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, palindrome

I have an assignment, I have to make a python code that checks whether a string is a palindrome using a recursive function that returns a boolean, but I am not allowed to use reversed slicing nor loops, and I am not allowed to change the function format, here's my code but it returns True all the time

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    res = []
    s = ['']
    if len(s) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        rev_s = is_palindrome(s[1:]) + s[0]
        res.append(rev_s)
        if res == s:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: You reassign `s` on the second line of your function to `['']`. Its length is always less than `2`, so you will always return `True`. I imagine you don't want that line: `s = ['']`.

Comment: misformatted - your identation is off. please fix.

Comment: You used a slicing here: `is_palindrome(s[1:])`.

Comment: @Thaa'er, It is also possible to achieve your target with the same function signature `with 1 pparameter`. The concept is to alter the parameter `(to list)` in 2nd recursive call. I have pasted the code in my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this counts as 'changing the function format', but here's my stab at a recursive version without slices:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
  def is_palindrome_r(i, j):
    if j <= i:
      return True
    if s[i] != s[j]:
      return False
    return is_palindrome_r(i + 1, j - 1)

  return is_palindrome_r(0, len(s) - 1)
```

The inner function, `is_palindrome_r`, is the recursive function that takes two indexes, `i` and `j`. The last line sets the initial positions for these two indexes at `0` (the start of the string) and `len(s) - 1` (the end of the string) and proceeds with the recursive logic. The recursive function has two exit conditions:

1. if `j <= i` we've reached the center of our palindrome. If we've gotten this far, we know all the other pairs of characters match and we don't need to do any more comparisons.
2. if the two characters pointed to by `i` and `j` *do not* match, it's definitely not a palindrome and we don't need to do any more comparisons.

Otherwise we don't yet know if the sequence is fully palindromic, so we we move our indexes one step inward (`i + 1, j - 1`) and go back to step 1.

Comment: Your code is correct and matches all the conditions in my question, but could you just explain more about what you did in the last two lines?

Comment: @Thaa'erSawaid I've provided a more thorough explanation above.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the first and the last character of the given string are the same and then recursively check if the remaining string is a palindrome instead:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner I believe the OP says only reversed slicing is not allowed.

Comment: Isn't s[-1] reversed?

Comment: ah so no  `k == k[::-1]` ?

Comment: @jimfawkes No, reversed slicing refers to the use of the third parameter of a slice constructor, e.g. `s[::-1]`.

Comment: @jimfawkes thats just taking the last character

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

No slicing used, just maintain the indices through the recursive calls

```
def is_palindrome(s):
  return helper(s, 0, len(s)-1)

def helper(s, i, j):
  if (i >= j):
    return True
  return s[i] == s[j] and helper(s, i+1, j-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mentioned function signature `def is_palindrome(s)` is the signature given by your teacher then no issue and there is no need to pass any extra parameter to achieve the goal.

Your teacher (or the one gave you this task is awesome) just wanted t check how do you handle this with only 1 parameter.

> The concept is very simple, just change the type of argument `(to list with 3 values)` in second recursive call.

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if type(s) is str:
        l = len(s) 

        if l == 0 or l == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return is_palindrome([s, 0, -1])
    else:
        string, start, end = s # s is list here

        if string[start] != string[end]:
            return False
        else:
            if(start + 1 >= end - 1):
                return True

            return is_palindrome([s, start + 1, end - 1])

def main():
    string1 = "abcba"
    string2 = "abcde"
    string3 = "AxxA"

    print(is_palindrome(string1)) # True
    print(is_palindrome(string2)) # False
    print(is_palindrome(string3)) # True

main();
```

> The following is not what you're looking for but may be you'll be looking for that in future.

```
>>> def is_palindrome(s):
...     if s == "".join(reversed(s)):
...         return True
...     else:
...         return False
...
>>> is_palindrome("ABA")
True
>>>
>>> is_palindrome("ABC")
False
>>>
>>> is_palindrome("XXZZXX")
True
>>>
>>> is_palindrome("@#7")
False
>>>
>>> is_palindrome("1@#@1")
True
>>>
```

Thank you.